Не удаляется белая полоса на ActivityMain
Не удаляется белая полоса на ActivityMain

я удалял и раздел fragment
и раздел comgoogleandroid
не помогает
еесли удаляю вылазят ошибки
как убрать белую полоску вверху? пустое пространство

А для чего вам paddingTop у корневого контейнера? Он и даёт вам "белую полосу", а точнее отступ от верхней границы.
